# Reference requestion: theorem guaranteeing self-embeddings of expansions of $\mathit{Ord}$

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, lo.logic, model-theory, higher-order-logics

This is an attempt to locate a theorem I vaguely remember but cannot find (which arose in the context of [Consistency of non-trivial elementary embedding $j : \mathit{Ord} \to \mathit{Ord}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3947955/28111) and motivated [Can $Ord$ have nontrivial second-order elementary self-embeddings?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/378918/can-ord-have-nontrivial-second-order-elementary-self-embeddings)). Specifically, I recall a theorem along the following lines (in contrast of course with the Kunen inconsistency):

> Every "reasonably definable" expansion of the class-sized structure $(\mathit{Ord}; \in)$ has nontrivial elementary self-embeddings.

Here the relevant notion of "reasonably definable" was broad enough to include the usual ordinal arithmetic operations, and if I recall correctly more complicated operations like $\alpha\mapsto\omega_\alpha$. On the other hand, it was a $\mathsf{ZFC}$ theorem, so we certainly can't go all the way to second-order logic (see [the MO question linked above](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/378918/can-ord-have-nontrivial-second-order-elementary-self-embeddings)).

Additionally, I vaguely recall that this was due to either Harvey Friedman or Mostowski and that the relevant definability notion was "least-fixed-point-flavored," but I'm much less confident about either of these memories.

Comment: Per [our earlier discussion](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/358914/turing-machines-with-all-runs-decidable#comment903034_358914), I used `\mathit` on your $\mathit{Ord}$s.  I also inlined the titles of the questions you reference.  I hope that this is all right.

Comment: @LSpice Fine by me! (And I totally forgot \mathit was an option ... again. :P)